# Binomial distribution problem needed some explanations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A course is divided into $n$ classes. There are exactly $r$ students enrolled in the course. Assume that each student chooses a class at random and that the capacity of each of the classes is unlimited.
>
> (a) Assume that there is only one class on Friday. What is the probability that there will be exactly k students in this Friday class ?
>
> (b) What is the probability that there will be at least one student in each of the classes?

For a, it's a binomial distribution so the answer is $\binom{ r  }{ k }$ ${(1- {1 \over n})}^{r-k}{({1 \over n})}^{k} $

For b, the answer is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k} \binom{ n  }{ k } {({ n-k \over n})}^{r} $$
(for r $\ge$ n)

Shouldn't it be something like ${1  - \binom{ r  }{ 0 } {(1- {1 \over n})}^{r-0}}  {({1 \over n})}^{0}$ =  ${1  - {(1- {1 \over n})}^{r}}$ 
for the probability that there will be at least 1 student in each of the classes = 1 - the probability of there will be no students in each of the classes? Can someone help me explain the answer for b?

Comment: For (a) the stated answer is correct.  For (b) the stated answer involving the summation is correct and the expression following "*shouldn't it be something like...*" is not.  The probability you wrote is the probability that there is at least one student *in the friday class specifically*, but it does not care about whether any of the tuesday classes have any students.

Comment: To correctly approach (b), apply the principle of [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) over the events "*There are no students in class $i$.*"  The union of those events is the opposite event to the one we are interested in.  Alternatively, a more advanced direct approach can be done using [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  It is worth knowing about them for the future, but the first approach is the one you are expected to be able to come up with.

Comment: @JMoravitz can you explain a little bit more, I can't still figure it out the the principle inclusion-exclusion :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the event that class $i$ has no students.

We are interested in finding the probability of $Pr(A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap \dots \cap A_n^c) = 1 - Pr(A_1\cup A_2\cup \dots \cup A_n)$

This expands via inclusion-exclusion as:

$=1 - Pr(A_1)-Pr(A_2)-\dots-Pr(A_n)+Pr(A_1\cap A_2)+Pr(A_1\cap A_3)+\dots+Pr(A_{n-1}\cap A_n)-Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)-\dots \pm \dots \pm Pr(A_1\cap \dots\cap A_n)$

Now... notice that $Pr(A_1)$ is the probability that no student was in class $1$ which can be found via binomial distribution as above or directly as $\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^r$.  Meanwhile $Pr(A_1\cap A_2)$ is the probability no student was in either of the first two classes, leaving $n-2$ available classes out of the $n$ for each and occurs with probability $\left(\dfrac{n-2}{n}\right)^r$.

In a similar fashion, you find that $Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_k)$, the probability that no student is in any of the first $k$ classes will be $\left(\dfrac{n-k}{n}\right)^r$

Finally, recognize that by symmetry, all probabilities involving the intersection of $k$ of these events will result in the same probability and so we may group them together, there being precisely $\binom{n}{k}$ different intersections involving exactly $k$ of the events.

Correctly accounting for the plus or minus that arises from inclusion exclusion, we arrive at a final probability of:

$$1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\left(\dfrac{n-k}{n}\right)$$

The only differences here to the formula given above is that I opted to write it so that we are subtracting the sum, hence the different exponent on the $-1$, and they stopped their summation at $n-1$ which doesn't affect anything since $Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_n)=0$ since obviously it is impossible for *every* class to be empty.